# javascript: list to enclose in div after n loop element

Tags: javascript, css

I have a long list of element generated by `for` loop of javascript. Initially I had only 4-5 elements and things were ok but now I have more than 30 elements making the list very long. I intend to enclose 5 elements in a `span` or `div` so that I can float it left and stack the list as columns but I am unable to get it working due to closing tag.

```
var ttllist="";
for(i=0;i<x.length;i++)
{
  if(i%5==0)
  {
     ttllst +='<span style="float:left">';
  }
  ttllst += x[i]+'<br/>';
//How to close the span tags accurately ???
}
return ttllist;
```

The problem I am facing is `x.length` can be any number and hence am left with unclosed tags some time. Can somebody please help.

Comment: can you create fiddle for that.... here is the link http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: You have probably a typo here - `ttllist` vs `ttllst`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can close the `span` tag before you start a new one, if the index is greater than 5.  Also you should close the tag at the very end, when you exit your loop.

```
var ttllst="";
for(i=0;i<x.length;i++)
{
  if(i%5==0)
  {
     if(i>0) {
       ttllst += '</span>';
     }
     ttllst +='<span style="float:left">';
  }
  ttllst += x[i]+'<br/>';
}
if (x.length > 0) {
  ttllst += '</span>';
}
return ttllst;
```

This is a basic example you may need further logic to cover other eventualities, but hopefully this helps.

Comment: This won't end the first `span`. the `i>5` condition is wrong.

Comment: Thanks, accepting it for simplicity. Also you edited the answer to make it correct.

Answer (score 0):

This should work. I've put in some comments to explain the logic.

```
var ttllist="";
for(i=0; i<x.length; i++) {
    if(i%5 == 0) {
        // if first item, don't close span
        if(i > 0) ttllst += '</span>'; 
        // if more to come, open new span
        if(i < x.length - 1) ttllst +='<span style="float:left">'; 
    }
    ttllst += x[i] + '<br/>';
    // if no more items to come, close last opened span
    if(i == x.length - 1) ttllst += '</span>'; 
}
return ttllist;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// function to render one block
function renderBlock(block) {
  var out = '';
  out += '<span style="float:left">';
  for(var j in block)
    out += block[j] + "<br/>";
  out += '</span>';    
  return out;
}     

var blocks = [],  // array to store blocks
    size = 5;     // items in one block

// split array into blocks 
while (x.length > 0)
    blocks.push(x.splice(0, size));

// render output
var ttllist = '';
for(var i in blocks) 
  ttllist += renderBlock(blocks[i]);
return ttlist;
```